# How to create an index in orientdb (native java api)

Tags: orientdb

I am getting the following warning when the graph starts to grow:

```
'bertex = false' fetched more than 50000 records: to speed up the execution, create an index or change the query to use an existent index
```

Is there a way to create the index from the java api?

I do not seem to find the right javadocs.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Hi, can you post the query? Thx in advance

Comment: graph.getVertices(s1, true).iterator();

Comment: Thx, one more thing ... what does s1 contains?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
graph.createKeyIndex("name", Vertex.class, new Parameter("type", "UNIQUE"));
```

For more information take a look at this link: http://orientdb.com/docs/2.1/Graph-Database-Tinkerpop.html#using-indices

Hope it helps.

Regards

Comment: thanks! I must have scrolled over this section too fast. sorry for wasting your time!

Comment: Don't worry, it's a pleasure